# how do I print unicode character in C encoded with UTF8?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, ncurses

I am trying to print magnifying glass (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50e/index.htm), and I get this error:

```
[niko@dev1 ncurses]$ gcc -o utf8 -std=c99 $(ncursesw5-config --cflags --libs) utf8.c 
utf8.c: In function ‘main’:
utf8.c:12:10: error: \ud83d is not a valid universal character
   printw("\ud83ddd0e\n");         // escaped Unicode 
          ^
[niko@dev1 ncurses]$ cat utf8.c
#include <locale.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  initscr();

  printw("\ud83ddd0e\n");         // escaped Unicode 

  getch();
  endwin();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What is the problem here? For, example, if I have a decimal number of encoding, which for magnifying glass is 55357 , how would I print it in printf to ncurses screen? (without using wchar_t because it wastes a lot of memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The information on [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50e/index.htm) is wrong. The escapes on the page are `\ud83d\udd0e`. This is an UTF-16 surrogate pair as used on Java, but it does not work on C, as GCC seems to require that one `\u` escape represent one Unicode codepoint, which half of the surrogate escape is not.

You should instead use `\U` (uppercase) with 8 hexadecimal digits, so U+1F50E becomes `\U0001F50E`. This escaped character is output correctly with `printf`.

---

P.S: if instead of magnifying glass you see something like `~_~T~N`, make sure that you've called the `setlocale` and actually linked against `-lncursesw`, failure to do either will mean that garbage will be printed instead.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Naturally

Comment: Aren't you required to write either an Unicode literal (`u"\U0001F50E"`) or just the bytes ("\xf0\x9f\x94\x8e")?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ah yes, `u8"\U0001F50E"` if you want `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not encode your string in UTF-16 (the `\ud8..\udd..`), but in UTF-8. To convert it, run this command:

```
perl -e 'print pack("H*","d83ddd0e")' | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-32 | hexdump -C
```

Then, you can see that your character is U+0001F50E. To insert this character back in your C code, use the `\U` sequence, with a capital U.

```
"\U0001F50E"
```

By the way, your number 55357 is not the magnifying glass (U+1F50E), but only the first half of the magnifying glass encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: I tried it but I don't get magnifying glass.However at least it compiles. Thanks!

Comment: it is not the first half, I printed  printw("\U0001F50E");  and got the complete magnifying glass

Comment: I wrote: _55357 is not the magnifying glass_. You instead thought that 0x1F50E were not the magnifying glass. These two are different numbers.

Comment: @Rolland Illig ooh, sorry, I got it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Some clarification is needed because OP asked more than one question:

- *What is the problem here?*

  Antti Haapala answered the important part, which dealt with the improperly represented character.
- *For, example, if I have a decimal number of encoding, which for magnifying glass is 55357 , how would I print it in printf to ncurses screen? (without using wchar_t because it wastes a lot of memory)*

  This was unanswered.  The comment about wasting memory overlooks the fact that ncurses (i.e., ***ncursesw***) will store all of that information in *complex characters*, which use even more memory than *wide characters* (`wchar_t`).

**`printw`** is similar to **`printf`**, but not identical.  To see this, the [`printw` manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_printw.3x.html) says

> The `printw`, `wprintw`, `mvprintw` and `mvwprintw` routines are  ***analogous***  to
>   **`printf`**  [see printf(3)].  In effect, the string that would be output by
>   **`printf`** is output instead as though waddstr were used on the given  window.

To understand what analogous means, a [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/analogous) might help (part of its meaning is "similar", but those are not synonymous).  But following the link to the [`waddstr` manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html):

> These functions write the (null-terminated) character string str on the
>   given window.  It is ***similar*** to calling **`waddch`** once for each  character
>   in the string.

Again, "similar" offers no guarantee that the behavior is identical.  The [`waddch` manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Character-Set) gives more information.  Among other things, it tells what translations it will do for control- and nonprinting-characters.  Also (the point) is that `waddch` in **ncurses** accepts a multibyte (read: "UTF-8") string and will display that if the locale and terminal support that.  That's different from X/Open Curses, as discussed in the [*Character Set*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Character-Set) subsection of the manual page's *PORTABILITY* section.

Those **`\u`** escapes tell the gcc to pass a UTF-8 string, which happens to work with ncurses.  The people concerned with standards will equivocate on whether it's guaranteed to work with `printf`, but let's not get into that swamp.

There is, by the way, no equivalent of `printw` which uses `wchar_t` arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can use putwchar (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/putwchar/) to print a wchar, but I don't believe it works for UTF-16 surrogate pairs.

In any case, printing unicode text to the terminal is always undefined behavior. On unix systems, most terminals emulate the VT-100, and are only guaranteed to support 7-bit ASCII text. (this why the `isprint` function exists).

Your best option is to use a library like freetype2 or cairo+pango to render text to a surface or pixmap in a graphical application.

Comment: It's usually implementation defined behaviour. On Linux with glibc, printing UTF-8 using C functionsjust works.

Comment: @DeftlyHacked are you sure about "undefined behaviour" ?VT-100 were in use 20 years ago. Today every linux installation has gnome terminal with 256 colors and unicode support. I am actually trying to create ncurses widgets with Unicode as a base for all the drawing.

Comment: Welcome to linux @Nulik, where technology stagnates because someone, somewhere wants continued support for the antikythera mechanism and a room sized IBM-650 using vacuum tubes instead of transisters; with drum memory and a teletype printer spooling sheets of output.

Comment: The way that all programming languages implement strings is kind of stupid in my opinion. there are 0x110000 (1,114,112) unicode character codes; requiring only 21-bits to store any character code. Only 10% have actually been designated. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are forms of compression rather than encodings. A smart implementation of strings would have an indexer that expands all code points to single UTF-32 characters.

Comment: @DeftlyHacked Why are you even discussing terminals? Did you know that terminals are technology from 1960s? If you don't want to use them, please, feel free not to - there are plenty of graphical user interfaces available. And if you don't like UTF-8 then use UTF-32. Your preferences have nothing to do with linux development.